# Problem with c++ function - error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [n]’

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, function-declaration, variable-length-array, incompatibletypeerror

i want to make function in c++ called 'losowanie', this function should random n numbers between 0-n. When i call this function, then i get :

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [n]’
```

Here is my code :

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
   
using namespace std;

int losowanie (int tab[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0;i<n; i++) {
        tab[i] = rand() % n + 1;
        cout<<tab[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = -1;
    
    while(n<0 || n>50) {
        cout<<"Give number (  0 - 50)"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
    }
    
    int tab[n];
    tab = losowanie(tab, n); //here is error
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `losowanie` is supposed to fill in the `tab` array in-place. What do you think it is supposed to return?

Comment: as @BoBTFish said, `losowanie` fills array in-place, simply remove that additional assignment to tab variable of the function result.
`losowanie(tab, n);`

Also that function should return an int (currently does not return anything), and your tab is int array

Answer (score 1):

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int tab[n];
```

is not a standard C++ feature. Instead use the standard container `std::vector`.

This while loop

```
while(n<0 || n>50) {
```

allows to enter the value 0 for the variable `n`. However you may not declare a variable length array with 0 elements.

The function `losowanie`

```
int losowanie (int tab[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0;i<n; i++) {
        tab[i] = rand() % n + 1;
        cout<<tab[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

has the return type `int` but returns nothing.

In this assignment statement

```
tab = losowanie(tab, n);
```

the left operand has the type `int[n]` while the return type of the function `int`. So the compiler issues an error because this statement does not make a sense. Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

You could change the type of the function from `int` to `void` and remove the assignment statement.

Also you should use the standard C function `srand` to get different sequences of random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

losowanie returns int, but tab is an array.
It is enough to make losowanie to a void function.

```
void losowanie (int tab[], int n) {
for(int i = 0;i<n; i++) {
    tab[i] = rand() % n + 1;
    cout<<tab[i]<<endl;
}
```

And, in main:

```
int tab[n];
losowanie(tab, n);
```